# How to rotate a symbol in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

In some of my tikz pictures I use symbols from the `fontawesome` package.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Question**

How can I rotate symbols in tikz?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Rocket
    \draw (0,0) node {\faRocket};
    % Rectangle
    \node [draw, thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=center] at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**What I tried so far**

`\draw[rotate=45] (0,0) node {\faRocket};` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Maybe not the best solution, but did you try `\draw (0,0) node[rotate=45] {\faRocket};`?

Comment: Well, I didn't. This does the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rotate the rocket symbol you could try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Rocket
    \draw (0,0) node[rotate=45] {\faRocket};
    % Rectangle
    \node [draw, thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=center] at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]